# Excel - keep the absolute reference from inserting row using COUNTIFS function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, countif

How can I use the absolute reference Column in a different sheet in COUNTIFS function?

COUNTIFS(Scenario!C:C,C21,Scenario!H:H,"*PASS*")

We are inserting new column on H, and then the reference range becomes I:I.

COUNTIFS(Scenario!C:C,C21,*Scenario!I:I*,"*PASS*")

This is checking each rows to count. 
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out.  It works with

COUNTIFS(OFFSET(Scenario!F:F,,1),"*PASS*",Scenario!C:C,C21)

Comment: Can you explain how this solved your problem? On this site we want others with your same question to get help too and giving just the formula in your answer doesn't accomplish that.

Answer (score -1):

**Your problem can be solved by using, "Naming the Range method":**

---

**Before Column Inserted:**

[image]

- Formula I've used in Cell `Y13`:

  `=SUMIF(MyName2,"A",MyName1)`
- Formula in Cell `Y14`:

`=COUNTIF(MyName1,1)+COUNTIF(MyName2,"A")`

---

**After Column Inserted:**

[image]

---

**My Recommendation:**

- Instead of COUNTIFS better use COUNTIF, as I 
  did with Formula in Cell `Y14`, because I've 
  observed that sometimes COUNTIFS ignores one of
  the Ranges.

**How it works:**

- Select required Range and from **FORMULA Tab** 
  Click **Define Name** then using Poped up 
  dialogue fill a Name and Cell Reference
  and finish with **Ok**.

[image]

**The reason I've suggested Name Range method 
  is,**

- Either INDERCT or even OFFSET can stops Excel 
  to loose the data after Column been inserted.
- But with Named Range, Excel automatically 
  adjusts data if & when the Column been 
  inserted.

---

**Use of INDIRECT, after Column Inserted:**

[image]

- *You may adjust cell references in the Formula 
  as needed.*

Comment: Write your concern that why this has been down voted !!